# Using while loop to copy files from the source to estination using PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell

I have PowerShell 4.0. I want to copy files from the source to the destination directory. I use `Get-ChildItem` and `Copy-Item` to copy the files to the destination. The count of files are 40 files.

The problem is that sometimes there is one file (it could be any file) that is not copied due to a network problem. In this case I will try to copy again by trying 5 attempts to see if the file is finally copied, otherwise I throw an exception and the copying stops. In my case I start copying everything all again.

How to copy the only file that does not copy and continue to the next one?

Here is my script:

```cs
function Get-ShortName {
    Begin {
        $fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
    }
    Process {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).ShortName
        } else {
            $fso.GetFile($_.FullName).ShortName
        }
    }
}

##Delete old files on th destination folder
Remove-Item "C:\Provisioning_Files\*.*"

Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\in\*.DT190223" -Exclude '*Denorms*' -Recurse |
    Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Provisioning_Files\" -Force -Verbose
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\in\*.DT190223" -Exclude '*Denorms*' -Recurse |
    Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Provisioning_Files\" -Force -Verbose
$checkprovfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Provisioning_Files -File
$File =  "C:\Provisioning_Files\*.*"
$MaxRetries = 5
$RetryCount = 0;
$Completed = $false

$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Provisioning_Files\*.*" | Get-Shortname

while (-not $Completed ) {
    if ($checkprovfiles.Count -eq 40) {
        Write-Verbose "The file are been all transferred to the destination path '$File'"
        $Completed = $true
    } else {
        if ($RetryCount -ge $MaxRetries) {
            Write-Verbose "Failed finding the file within '$MaxRetries' retries"
            throw "Failed finding the file within '$MaxRetries' retries"
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "File not found, retrying in 5 seconds."
            Start-Sleep '5'
            Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\in\*.DT190223" -Exclude '*Denorms*' -Recurse |
                Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Provisioning_Files" -Force -Verbose
            Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\in\*.DT190201" -Exclude '*Denorms*' -Recurse |
                Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Provisioning_Files" -Force -Verbose
            $RetryCount++
        }
    }
```

As you can see the last 3 lines show that I start the copy all over again. I just want to recopy the file that did not.

Comment: You're trying to re-invent [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). Don't do that.

Comment: I did not understand what you said. Could you tell me more? Thanks

Comment: Ditto to what Ansgar just stated. He also provided you a link to the tool.  Just click on the word. RoboCopy is built-in to Windows and is a far superior option to what you are trying to recreate using PowerShell. We all are PowerShell fans, what Ansgar is saying, is use the right tool for a given task. He is not saying you cannot do what you are doing, but suggesting the Robocopy use to get you to your end goal more quickly / simply. You can combine PowerShell and Robocopy if you choose. See --- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Using-Powershell-to-eef43000

Comment: Thanks I do appreciate your help.  In the code I provided... where robocopy will be inserted into? I never use robocopy in the past, Sorry if I ask too much.

Comment: @serob - if the document link provided is not enuf to understand what robocopy is/can-do, then perhaps this will help ... Robocopy - Wikipedia — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Comment: `robocopy` already does everything your script is trying to do (and more). Drop your script and just use `robocopy` instead.

Comment: Thank for your help. Yes. Robocopy is working exactly the way I wanted to work. Only these 2 lines below is doing what I wanted to achieve with the code above. Thanks Guys.

Comment: Robocopy  E:\source\in \\destination\Provisioning_Files "*nightly.out*" /s /MAXAGE:$TodayDate

Comment: Robocopy  E:\source\in \\destination\Provisioning_Files "*monthly.out*" /s /MAXAGE:$sysMonth